# 2D array outputing different values if you print it by line of the entire array in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

Hey StackOverflow community!

I've got a weird thing happening in my C code.

Here the part of the code concerned :

( "tab4" is a 16 length,  1 dimension array, filled with ints, "tab" is a 4x4 2D array filled with 0s)

I'm trying to put the values of tab4 in "tab" (each line of "tab" gets 4 digits of tab4)

I've put some prints to test results

```
for (int u = 0; u < 4; u++)
        {
            tab[0][u] = tab4[u];
            printf(" %d ", tab[0][u]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        for (int yu = 4; yu < 8; yu++)
        {
            tab[1][yu] = tab4[yu];
            printf(" %d ", tab[1][yu]);

        }
        printf("\n");
        for (int cont = 8; cont < 12; cont++)
        {
            tab[2][cont] = tab4[cont];
            printf(" %d ", tab[2][cont]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        for (int ye = 12; ye < 16; ye++)
        {
            tab[3][ye] = tab4[ye];
            printf(" %d ", tab[3][ye]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                printf(" %d ", tab[i][y]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n\n");
```

The weird thing happening here is that when I print "tab" line by line, it works, but when I print it as a whole, it doesn't.

Here is my output :

```
This is the array, printed line by line
 16  8  4  0
 8  64  0  0
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0

here is the array printed as a whole

 16  8  4  0
 0  0  0  0
 8  64  0  0
 0  0  0  0
```

This may be linked to some warning I have :

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning C6386   Buffer overrun while writing to 'tab[1]':  the writable size is '16' bytes, but '20' bytes might be written.
>
> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'tab[1]':  the readable size is '16' bytes, but '20' bytes may be read.

(same warning for all "for" loops)

I know it means that I'm trying to write somewhere I shouldn't, but I don't know how I could possibly be doing that

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Please edit your question adding a [mre], starting from the exact declaration of `tab4` and `tab`.

Comment: `tab[1][4]` does not exist. You want `tab[1][yu - 4] = tab4[yu];` ... same for other loops

Comment: *""tab" is a 4x4 2D"* - which means every loop except the first is wrong. They're all accessing index >= 4 in the inferior dimension of `tab`.

Comment: what you are trying to do with 4 loops (except the inner prints) can be done with one single statement: `memcpy(tab, tab4, sizeof tab4);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loops such that

```
    for (int yu = 4; yu < 8; yu++)
    {
        tab[1][yu] = tab4[yu];
        printf(" %d ", tab[1][yu]);

    }
```

are incorrect. The second "row" (one-dimensional array) of the array `tab` has the range of valid indices [0, 4).

So you need it rewrite at least like

```
    for (int yu = 4; yu < 8; yu++)
    {
        tab[1][yu-4] = tab4[yu];
        printf(" %d ", tab[1][yu-4]);

    }
```

Or you could fill the array tab using the following loops

```
for ( int i = 0, k = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
    {
        tab[i][j] = tab4[k++];
        printf(" %d ", tab[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Or

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
    {
        tab[i][j] = tab4[4 * i + j];
        printf(" %d ", tab[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: oh my god I can't believe I made this mistake! Thanks for the input I'll be more careful in the future  :) !